# Nomination edit page not responsive enough (yet)

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, responsive-design

The page for adding/editing your nomination during an [election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election) has been made (partially) responsive already; the top bar is optimized for the small width and the sidebar widget is moved to the bottom.

However, the text area itself is too wide, unlike e.g. the [Contact Us](/contact) page where its width has been reduced appropriately.

[image]

Comment: (yes, I've noted the irony of testing an Android election page on an iPhone)

Comment: Also applies for normal election page

Comment: The normal election page isn't responsive at all, which means they've probably not gotten to it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now: both the excessive width for the editor, and the complete lack of editing buttons in the toolbar.

Thanks for reporting this!